# How can I post to friends wall as Post to others wall is no more existing in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I used the following code to post on friends wall

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
attachment.put("message", "Messages");
attachment.put("name", "Get thisapp to send messages like this!");
 attachment.put("href", link);
parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
parameters.putString("message", msg);
parameters.putString("target_id", “friend id”);
parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
 String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
             Log.v("response***********", response);
```

But I get the following error in response

```
02-25 16:12:24.365: V/response***********(6540): {"error_code":200,"error_msg":"Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application"
```

I referred this link https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013 . If Facebook doesn't support graph api to post to others wall, how can I post to friends wall?

Answer (score 0):

> If Facebook doesn't support graph api to post to others wall, how can I post to friends wall?

There is no way, it was disabled due to abuse of the feature. If Facebook says no, then workarounds are illogical.